# How can i make advanced UI design in flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Can anyone tell me how I can make UI like this image. I am especially interested in body parts. hope you understand the question. your help will be very appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: 100,
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Card(
            elevation: 15,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  top: 10,
                  left: 10,
                  child: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 10,
                  right: 10,
                  child: Icon(Icons.print),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Card(
            elevation: 15,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  top: 10,
                  left: 10,
                  child: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 10,
                  right: 10,
                  child: Icon(Icons.print),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Put it into body and you can customize the Icon with other widget like Switcher,...

Comment: Nice, but i want that icon also at the end of widget. i mean as you did two icon upper side i want to icon lower side also

Comment: Just use Positioned and set bottom, right or left. Every where you want in that Card widget, you can check the example of Positioned widget here https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Positioned+widget